# How to change the center of mass?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I am try

```
MassData md = mBody.getMassData();
md.center.set(2f, 0); mBody.setMassData(md);
```

But this is not working properly. Help me do this correctly. 
I want add a bit more weight to the bottom half of my body.

Comment: Please define 'not working'. Does anything change?

Comment: Have you found your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change mass directly, what you want to do is to add an extra fixture to the bottom of your body. You can do it e.g. like this (this is a snippet, not complete code; create your textures, scene etc).

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2, 32, 32, mDTextureRegion, vbom);

Body body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, sprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f)); // create a simple circle body from the sprite
scene.attachChild(sprite);
Debug.i("ORIG MASS Y: " + body.getMassData().center.y); // this is just generated info
FixtureDef fd = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10f, 1f, 1f, true); // high density fixture; it is a sensor, i.e. it won't affect collisions
CircleShape cs = new CircleShape(); 
cs.setRadius(0.1f); // make it very small
fd.shape = cs;
cs.setPosition(new Vector2(0, -0.5f)); // attach below the current centre

body.createFixture(fd); // attach to body
Debug.i("NEW MASS Y: " + mDBody.getMassData().center.y); // the generated info changed

mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sprite, body, true, true));
```

This example body will behave like a spintop, it will try to reposition itself so the bottom of the sprite will touch the ground. When you rotate it, it will try to get to that position again.